# how to store array values in single field database using json_encode in luman?

Tags: php, json, web-services, laravel

how to store array values in the single field database using  json_encode in luman?

I get value from the request:

```
 $qualification_id = array($request->input('qualification_id'));
```

my json encode line:

```
$serializedArr=json_encode( $qualification_id);
```

my insert query:

```
$result = DB::insert("insert into `borrower_registration` 
                          (first_name,middle_name,last_name,city_id,
                            state_id,dob,marital_id,father_husband,
                            institute,qualification_id,graduated_id) 
                       values ('$first_name',' $middle_name','$last_name','$city_id',
                                '$state_id ','$dob ',' $marital_id','$father_husband',
                                '$institute','$serializedArr','$graduated_id')");
```

I given sample input for the array 1,2,3,4 and using

```
 print_r($qualification_id)
```

and get output like **[1,2,3,4]**

data type of the column qualification_id is **int**

I execute the code and it store in database as **0** .please give valuable suggestions.

Comment: Why do you suddenly decide to stop the double quoted string to add the `$serializedArr` value to the value list?

Comment: Start by showing us a `print_r($qualification_id) and then an `echo $serializedArr;` Edit the question with the output from those 2 lines

Comment: Also show us the data type of the column `qualification_id` from your schema

Comment: ok , i will update

Comment: By the way, storing multiple keys in a string column is a totally bad idea.

Comment: Change the DATA TYPE of `qualification_id` to TEXT or VARCHAR or if you are using a mysql5.7 version maybe `JSON`

Comment: @RiggsFolly Yes ,now only i randomly changed date type and its worked for  VARCHAR. Thanks anyway .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if `qualification_id` column has [`JSON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html) or [`TEXT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/blob.html) format.

Comment: Strinctly the column data type `JSON` or `TEXT` or `VARCHAR` would make NO difference in and insert, as long as the data is in fact a string

Comment: @AshwinSakthi, so you're trying to persist `JSON` data as `INT`, that's why you're getting `0`. Try to change it to `JSON` or `TEXT`.

Comment: If you can `print_r($serializedArr);` then its not a string its still a PHP Array

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin ,hi i change int to text ,its shows some  errors.

Comment: @RiggsFolly,yes dude.

Comment: @AshwinSakthi you didn't tell anything about errors, you said you're getting `0`. If you're getting an error, please post it here. If it's still `0` what does `dd($serializedArr);` show if you put it after `$serializedArr = json_encode($qualification_id);`?

Comment: @AlexeyMezenin as per your instruction ,i saved datatype int to text ,its showed error.